# Don't allow you to choose impossible badges on the new profile page

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, per-site-meta

The new profile pages let you choose a badge to track, but it allows you to choose impossible badges!

For example, on per-site-meta sites, where you cannot start bounties on questions, you can choose to track 'Promoter' ('First bounty you offered on your own question'): (image from per-site-meta site:)

[image]

Can we either have an error message (or information dialog) when selecting an impossible badge? Or just not show impossible badges? Please?

More examples:

- <s>Legendary (Earned 200 daily reputation 150 times)</s> (@animuson told me how to get this!)
- Altruist (First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question)
- <s>Epic (Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times)</s> (@animuson told me how to get this!)
- Informed (Read the entire tour page)

Comment: You *can* earn Epic and Legendary on Meta. And the tracking for them actually works properly.

Comment: @animuson how...?

Comment: It just runs calculations based off the votes you received rather than an actual reputation number.

Comment: @animuson Ahh.. ok - but you still can't earn informed and altruist and promotor... can you?

Comment: You're limiting this to *globally* impossible, right?  Versus, say, not being eligible for certain badges because of characteristics of your account?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well... globally in the sense of child-meta globally. Guess you could say ineligible but that's not because of the characteristics of your account exactly... more to do with where you actually are!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant -- "is available on this site" is a different kind of check from "is available for this user on this site".  The latter could lead into a rat's nest of conditions and interactions pretty quickly, so best to avoid that.

Comment: Another point of this would be not to show Excavator and Archaeologist on sites younger than 6 months old